# VM gaming vs a bunch of cheap PCs

Tags: virtual-machine, gaming

I need to set up 10 spaces for online gaming like League of Legends and Smite.

I am considering the pro/con of 1 server with 10 VM systems... or 10 individual low end (600 to 700 dollar gaming systems) I am reading that there are some problems with VM gaming so I am beginning to feel that the VM option is not viable but I hoped to hear a more detailed explanation if possible.

budget for this is 10k

Thank you for you input

Comment: Hardware and service recommendations are not on topic here at Superuser

Answer (score 2):

[PC-over-IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teradici) is the only protocol I've seen that does a good job of transmitting video... but I doubt it'll handle the frames per second (FPS) requirements of games.

10 individual game machines is a good idea. If you have exactly the same specs for the 10 machines, you just need one base image with games. Whenever the system needs to be repaired, you can restore the base image. The only maintenance would be to update the image any time you add or remove games.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking into developing a bunch of VM systems then it is best to look into what is known as a VDI (Virtual Desktop environment), specifically a tool called VDI in a box.

```
http://www.citrix.com/products/vdi-in-a-box/overview.html
```

As mentioned on the website this can cut infrastructure costs by up to 60%, Since you are going to have up to 10 computers running lol then the bandwidth and the hardware needed will be quite a lot to handle and the data needs to be distributed along the network.

The basic idea on VDI is you would have 10 pc's with the basic hardware which is very cheap in itself, then the VDI-in-a-box connected to a server basically hosts all the Operating system images within the server and the pc's basically access the OS with all the installed programs i.e. lol through the network for the clients to play on.

You can find more detail on the website but I believe this will be the cheapest option as the licencing for each VM will be cheaper than the computer itself, the majority of the costs will go towards your server hosting these services along with a virtualised GPU unit to run the game on the server.